# Inserting a video in asp .net web page in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to insert a video in asp .net webpage in visual studio 2010, but was unsuccessful. Is it tht videos can't be inserted in webpages of vs 2010 ?

Comment: How did you attempt to insert a video into your webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="your source" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

**Or:**

```
 <object data="your source" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="100%" height="100%">
   <param name="src" value="your source">
   <param name="autoStart" value="00">
   <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
   <param name="allowScriptAcess" value="always">
 </object>
```